# what the difference of supported pl languages between hawq and other databases?

Tags: hawq

what the difference of supported pl languages between hawq and other databases ? I want to compare the supported pl languages between hawq and other databases. Does hawq support more than some databases ? Or will hawq support more in the future ?

Answer (score 1):

The procedural language in HAWQ is similar to that in Greenplum Database and PostgreSQL in design and implementation perspective. It is rich in supported procedural language, as well as extensibility to add new procedural language.

The difference of procedural language between HAWQ and that in PostgreSQL is that user-defined function is executed in parallel by leveraging HAWQ's MPP architecture.

Other than the SQL, C Language, and Internal language, hawq currently support a lot of procedural language including plpgsql, plr, plpythonu, pljava, pljavau, plperl, plperlu, etc.

Answer (score 0):

One advantage for HAWQ is parallel executing these pl functions, which maybe not the feature level.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to http://hdb.docs.pivotal.io/20/plext/UsingProceduralLanguages.html for all the supported pl languages by hawq.

Answer (score 0):

For the last part of the question: `Does hawq support more than some databases?`, the answer is **YES**.

HAWQ is planning to design a fresh, pluggable framework supporting many file systems + many formats. The basic idea comes from ORC supporting, and I think this framework could also support other databases such as postgres, mysql, oracle, redis and so on. It is something beyond but similar with the latest Postgres's FDW feature.

Some references are listed below:

[HAWQ-786](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HAWQ-786)

[FDW](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/fdw%C2%ADcallbacks.html)